# Dual citizen Canada / USA

Tags: usa, canada, us-citizens, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens

I currently live in Canada right now. I am going to the US next week but I am a dual citizen, Canada and US. How do I exit Canada and enter the US?

Answer (score 4):

There are no exit procedures for either country.

As a dual citizen you should have passports for both countries.  You should use your American passport to fly to the US and to present at US border control.  You should use your Canadian passport to fly to Canada and to present at Canadian border control.

Some will say that you don't need both passports, and it's true that neither country can refuse you entry, but the onus will be on you to prove citizenship.  A passport is the best proof of this.  You won't be denied entry once your citizenship is established, but if you have no passport for that nationality, there might be delays while your citizenship is verified.  Note that a birth certificate is not standalone proof of citizenship, as citizenship can be surrendered.

Comment: Canada officially recognizes that its citizens can fly to and enter Canada with US passports, though it does also say that a Canadian passport is the best way to prove Canadian nationality when traveling.

Comment: @phoog You only get the rights of citizenship if you can prove your citizenship.  A passport is the best proof of citizenship.

Comment: "Best" doesn't mean "only," however. It's also possible to be admitted without proving citizenship, of course. Note the "exception" on the page [Dual Canadian citizens need a valid Canadian passport](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/dual-canadian-citizens-visit-canada.html): "If you are an American-Canadian dual citizen with a valid U.S. passport, you don’t need a Canadian passport to fly to Canada. However, you will still need to carry proper identification and meet the basic requirements to enter Canada."

Comment: @phoog That exception really is about the fact that Canadian citizens are ineligible for an eTA.  US citizens don't require one, so it's still possible to enter Canada as a Canadian citizen with a US passport, even though it isn't recommended.  A birth certificate alone is not sufficient proof of citizenship.

Comment: That may all be true, but none of it changes the fact that the "some" in your statement that "some will say that you don't need both passports" includes the government of Canada itself.  The government may prefer Canadian/US dual citizens to have Canadian passports, but the government nonetheless recognizes that Canadian/US dual citizens do not necessarily need a Canadian passport to enter Canada.

Comment: The cost of a Canadian passport is much less than the potential hardship caused by a missed flight.  I'll stick to my original advice.